# nodemailer is returning is not a constructor + unhandled promise rejection

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have a main index.js and calling the nodemailer with

```
  new aaaaa.send(`${userEmail}`)
```

and this is my nodemailer.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const EmailTemplate = require('email-templates');

const {
  nodemailer_client_secret,
  nodemailer_refresh_token,
  nodemailer_access_token,
  nodemailer_user,
  nodemailer_client_id,
  sp_auth,
} = require('../../config/config');
const { gmail } = require('googleapis/build/src/apis/gmail');

class aaaaa {
  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  static async send(userEmail, blackListRandom) {

    const emailVerify = await nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: nodemailer_user,
        clientId: nodemailer_client_id,
        clientSecret: nodemailer_client_secret,
        refreshToken: nodemailer_refresh_token,
        accessToken: nodemailer_access_token,
        expires: 3600,
      },
    });

    const email = new EmailTemplate({
      transport: emailVerify,
      send: true,
      preview: false,
    });
    email
      .send({
        template: 'hiii',
        message: {
          from: '',
          to: userEmail,
        },
        locals: {
        },
      })
      .then(() => console.log('email has been sent!'))
  }
}

module.exports = aaaaa;
```

I receive emails from this mail. However, how can I get rid of the two warnings that I get from?

- UnhandlePromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError is not a constructor
- unhandle promise rejection?

Comment: It's mean you should add `try/catch` or `then/catch`  for `send` function or add a `UnhandlePromiseRejection` event listener at top level of your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend removing the `new` keyword or splitting it out into a new line as it is being applied to the static method, which is causing the error.

```js
const emailObj = new aaaaa();
emailObj.send(`${userEmail}`);
```

Comment: It is a static function so does't need new at all

Comment: Is there any reason that this does not trigger an error?